# Extraer datos de forma automática y diaria

Tags: base-de-datos

Editado:
Necesito poder extraer 3 columnas diariamente que son nombres de los clientes tipo string y 2 columnas de tipo int  que son datos numéricos de  deudas y  aportes.
y estas pasarlas a otra base de datos de forma automática.

Comment: mmmm esto suena raro.. podrias dar mas informacion al respecto?que quiere decir sin que afecte la seguridad??

Comment: Necesitas añadir más detalles. Tal y como está ahora la pregunta, es demasiado amplia y las respuestas que vas a obtener van a ser más bien genéricas y amplias y puede que no te sirvan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones:

1. Crear interfaces, osea stores programados que pasen información de una BD a otra,  pasar toda la información nueva de las tablas de sucursales a una tabla en el servidor donde tendrás toda la información centralizada.  Esto lo tendrias que programar tu desde cero.

   NOTA: Para esto tendrías que tener acceso a todas las sucursales, puedes abrir el acceso utilizando linked servers en el caso de SQL.  Y si estas en VPN pues el acceso es directo como si estuvieras en la red local.  Otra forma es con la IP publica de la sucursal.  Todo esto dependerá de tus necesidades.
2. Utilizar replicas.  En SQL existen las replicas, las cuales te permiten transferir o replicar información de una base de datos a otra o pasar información de un server a otro.  Las replicas hacen la transferencia de información de forma automática, solo se necesitan configurar y ya.
3. Crear archivos planos, puedes exportar la información desde la BD a un archivo plano TXT para después mediante red o FTP tomar ese archivo he integrarlo mediante bulk insert en tu BD.
4. Programar Servicios, puedes programar servicios que acumulen la información y la envíen a tu servidor, proceso que este corriendo en background y que tome la información de las sucursales y la envié a tu servidor centralizado, esto puede ser mediante internet con webService, o mediante Servicios de windows o un programa que se este ejecutando, como mejor te convenga.

Es tu decisión que te conviene mas o como quieres resolver ese detalle, cualquiera de las opciones que te propongo se realizarían automáticamente sin estar molestan a las personas en la sucursal, todo desde BD.